# How to make two <ul> dependent to each other as if they were selects?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Wondering how to make two unordered lists be dependent as if they were selects.

I have this ul and this select (HTML):

```
<div class="wrapper-demo">
    <div id="dd" class="wrapper-dropdown-3" tabindex="1">
        <span>Ciudad</span>
        <ul class="dropdown" tabindex="1" id="ps">
            <li data-selector=".group-germ"><a href="#">Germany</a></li>
            <li data-selector=".group-sp"><a href="#">Spain</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>

<select id="select_act" style="display:none" class="group group-germ">
    <option>Bayern Munich</option>
    <option>Borussia Dortmund</option>
</select>

<select id="select_act2" style="display:none" class="group group-sp">
    <option>Real Madrid</option>
    <option>FC Barcelona</option>
</select>
```

And this JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('ul.dropdown').on('click', '>li>a', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('.group').hide();
        $($(this).parent('li').attr('data-selector')).show();
    }).children('li:first').children('a:first').click();
});
```

The thing is I want to turn the last two selects into lists too and sill be dependent on the first list. How can this be achieved?

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/wY9D6/

Comment: can you make [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) which will be helpful for us?

Comment: can you clarify what exactly you mean by "and still be dependent on the first list"?

Comment: Done JSFiddle. By "and still be dependent on the first list" I just meant that I want the lists to be dependent. Perhaps an unfortunate sentence anyways.